iptables adding localhost once adds the rule twice
I am trying to whitelist memcached port 11211 on ipv4 with iptables v1.8.4:
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 11211 -s localhost -j ACCEPT;

Whenever I run that command, then listing the rules, that rule is there twice.
I don't understand why.
Is it because command host localhost returns 2 records ? (one ipv4 and one ipv6) ?
The duplicate rules don't happen when I whitelist 127.0.0.1
Is it a better / accepted practice to add rules for 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost ?
[root @s1]# iptables -F
[root @s1]#

[root @s1]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
[root @s1]#

[root @s1]# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 11211 -s localhost -j ACCEPT;
[root @s1]#
[root @s1]#
[root @s1]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  localhost.localdomain  anywhere             tcp dpt:memcache
ACCEPT     tcp  --  localhost.localdomain  anywhere             tcp dpt:memcache

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
[root @s1]#

[root @s1]# host localhost
localhost has address 127.0.0.1
localhost has IPv6 address ::1
[root @s1]#


edit: here is another output using iptables-save after each flush or add command, and listing rules with iptables -S:
[root@s1]#
[root@s1]# iptables -F
[root@s1]#
[root@s1]# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Thu Sep 12 16:03:09 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Sep 12 16:03:09 2024
[root@s1]#
[root@s1]#
[root@s1]# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 11211 -s localhost -j ACCEPT;
[root@s1]#
[root@s1]#
[root@s1]# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Thu Sep 12 16:03:18 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11211 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11211 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Sep 12 16:03:18 2024
[root@s1]#
[root@s1]#
[root@s1]#
[root@s1]# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11211 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 11211 -j ACCEPT
[root@s1]#
[root@s1]#
[root@s1]# host localhost
localhost has address 127.0.0.1
localhost has IPv6 address ::1
[root@s1]#
[root@s1]#


That would be the plausible explanation if localhost has two IPv4 addresses. iptables command works only for IPv4; there is another front-end, ip6tables, to work with IPv6. I guess, if you use iptables-save to list the contents of the firewall instead of iptables -L (which reverse-resolves addresses and ports to names, which hinder things), it'll be easier to understand what's happening. Also, don't do just iptables -F and pretend there's nothing: actually run iptables-save two times, before and after your command, to be certain.

Please don't post the output of iptables -L when asking iptables related question; it excludes a great deal of important information. Replace that output with the output of iptables -S or iptables -S -t <table>  (for a single table), or iptables-save (to show the entire configuration).

I added another output using iptables-save and iptables -S

@NikitaKipriyanov yes, you are correct about the ip6tables, I am using that one too for ipv6 ips, but for this exact issue I think it does not interfere. Except that I used localhost instead of actual IPs in order to have more static rules that would work on both iptables and ip6tables, but I get to learn I need to use iptables 127.0.0.1 and ipv6tables ::1

It's reasonable to always use resolved IP addresses with firewall, and not names. There are several causes of frustration when you use name: in addition to this one (adding several rules on a single command), names are being resolved once and never stored, so when the DNS changes, the firewall rules don't and it is sometimes unclear why some addresses ever appeared in the firewall. The core reason is that firewall is L3 or L4 thing, while DNS is higher level, and it is conceptually wrong to make lower levels to logically depend on higher levels.

I will try to use ips instead of hostnames, in some cases it works well with hostnames, if my home ISP has a static hostname for me and my ip changes every week or so, a SSH server can clear the rule and  whitelist my IP again based on hostname every hour or so.

Indeed : when you use a hostname with iptables rules, that hostname will first be resolved (by the system resolver library) and from there iptables only uses the IP-address that gets discovered, not the hostname.
When a hostname resolves to multiple IP-addresses, or for example is a round-robin DNS record, IIRC all IP-addresses get used.
It would be interesting to see what for example getent hosts localhost returns , I expect two addresses, as that would explain why two rules get created.

Update
Now with access to a system I can safely play with:
I can easily recreate what is happening for you when I add a second localhost entry to /etc/hosts
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   localhost

That will result in the same behaviour designed for hosts that use round robin DNS records like www.google.com when adding iptables rules:
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m comment --comment "testing round-robin-dns" -s localhost -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m comment --comment "testing round-robin-dns" -s www.google.com -j ACCEPT

That results in multiple rules that get created, 1 for each IPv4 unique addresses that the hostname resolves to:
iptables-save |grep "testing round-robin-dns"

-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m comment --comment "testing round-robin-dns" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m comment --comment "testing round-robin-dns" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 142.250.102.99/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m comment --comment "testing round-robin-dns" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 142.250.102.103/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m comment --comment "testing round-robin-dns" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 142.250.102.105/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m comment --comment "testing round-robin-dns" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 142.250.102.106/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m comment --comment "testing round-robin-dns" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 142.250.102.104/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m comment --comment "testing round-robin-dns" -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 142.250.102.147/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -m comment --comment "testing round-robin-dns" -j ACCEPT

Since my test system is dual stack getent hosts localhost and getent hosts www.google.com defaults to returning only IPv6 addresses I had to test resolving with the getent ahostsv4 localhost command, but that returns exactly the 2 127.0.0.1 addresses for localhost and list of IPv4 IP-addresses that get added for Google :
getent ahostsv4 localhost
127.0.0.1       STREAM localhost
127.0.0.1       DGRAM
127.0.0.1       RAW
127.0.0.1       STREAM
127.0.0.1       DGRAM
127.0.0.1       RAW

142.250.102.147 STREAM www.google.com
142.250.102.147 DGRAM
142.250.102.147 RAW
142.250.102.99  STREAM
142.250.102.99  DGRAM
142.250.102.99  RAW
142.250.102.106 STREAM
142.250.102.106 DGRAM
142.250.102.106 RAW
142.250.102.105 STREAM
142.250.102.105 DGRAM
142.250.102.105 RAW
142.250.102.104 STREAM
142.250.102.104 DGRAM
142.250.102.104 RAW
142.250.102.103 STREAM
142.250.102.103 DGRAM
142.250.102.103 RAW

getent most closely resembles how the system resolver works, where utilities like host and dig are exclusively DNS oriented. AFAIK the STREAM address will be used for TCP, the DGRAM for UDP and RAW by raw TCP sockets).
Note that iptables uses IP-addresses in the actual rule set and does not store the hostname. When you don't use -n iptables will do a reverse DNS lookup which can take a long time and which can have interesting/confusing results for hosts where the forward DNS record you used to create the rule doesn't align with the reverse PTR DNS records, like withe the Google IP-addresses ( www.google.com has disappeared and instead you see 1e100.net hosts)
iptables  -L  |grep "testing round-robin-dns"

ACCEPT     tcp  --  localhost            anywhere             tcp dpt:https /* testing round-robin-dns */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  localhost            anywhere             tcp dpt:https /* testing round-robin-dns */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  rb-in-f99.1e100.net  anywhere             tcp dpt:https /* testing round-robin-dns */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  rb-in-f103.1e100.net  anywhere             tcp dpt:https /* testing round-robin-dns */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  rb-in-f105.1e100.net  anywhere             tcp dpt:https /* testing round-robin-dns */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  rb-in-f106.1e100.net  anywhere             tcp dpt:https /* testing round-robin-dns */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  rb-in-f104.1e100.net  anywhere             tcp dpt:https /* testing round-robin-dns */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  rb-in-f147.1e100.net  anywhere             tcp dpt:https /* testing round-robin-dns */

Conclusion
Since the Linux packet filter works on packets and streams that only contain numerical IP-addresses as sources and destination, don't use DNS names to create rules, but use numerical IP-addresses when creating rule-sets.

The command getent hosts localhost returns this: ::1 localhost.localdomain localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback, I am unsure what that means, but the host localhost command is more clear to me and that returns both 127.0.0.1 and ::1, I assume the 2 commands are related.

That would be very kind of you if you can also explain how one IPv4 address and one IPv6 address happens to make two rules in the IPv4 ruleset. If there were two IPv4 addresses, there would be no questions, but the second one simply doesn't fit... What if that happens to be not localhost, but some other name that has one IPv4 and one IPv6? Does it involve reverse lookups somehow (e.g. maybe ::1 sent to iptables makes it to find a corresponding IPv4 address by making reverse and then forward lookup)? Very curious.

@NikitaKipriyanov I was able to test and expand my original answer to exactly replicate the issue and resulting rule sets

@HBruijn so it is because host localhost returns 2 ipv4 related ips/hosts ? Not because one is ipv4 and one is ipv6 ? I tested with host cloudflare.com, it shows 2 ipv4 and 2 ipv6; for Cloudflare, the iptables command adds 2 ipv4 rules and ip6tables adds 2 ipv6 rules. That makes sense so far, but ...

but ... getent hosts localhost shows ::1 localhost.localdomain localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback  which to me it looks like 3 are ipv6 related, but I see adding a localhost rule by ip6tables only adds one rule and by iptables adds 2 rules.

The conclusion is clear thou, I better use ips and not hostnames in iptables :)

host queries DNS while getent ahostsv4 localhost more closely resembles the system / glibc resolver IPv4 lookups and also includes the etc/hostsfile.
